Replacing a small rotted deck, question about framing/step
So the small deck (or patio? it barely feels worth calling a deck at this point) on the front door of my house was rotted and sagging, so I pulled it out. After going over the DCA6 guide, I realized it was improperly anchored to a chimney bay. I've been trying to figure out a way to set up the framing so I don't need to add any posts.
I've added three annotated images of the area - I've marked the actual places I can have ledger boards in blue, the chimney in red (there was a ledge anchored there that shouldn't have been), and we have a large concrete pad that I marked in yellow. The concrete pad is about a 15" drop from the top of the decking. Apologies in advance for the garbage handwriting. Basically there are three walls I can anchor a ledger to, but the concrete pad is too far away if I have my joists at 90° to the ledgers. I think if I go at an angle with the joists the span is small enough that I don't need a footing post.
I've also uploaded a framing plan I think I settled on, using some 45 degree joist hangers (and hopefully trying to pry them to the actual 51 degrees needed). If I understand the guide correctly, I don't actually need any posts to support the deck. Then I'll just add a box step to the front, resting on the concrete pad and anchored to the rim joist.
So my main questions are:

Am I correct that I wouldn't need a support post?
Is there a better way to do a single step besides using a hidden joist hanger?
I plan on doing picture frame decking with the main boards going perpendicular to the joists, is that reasonable?
And any other tips/things I'm missing? I don't have experience building decks, so any insight here would be valuable.

Deck area 1 - valid ledgers in blue dashes

Deck area 2 - valid ledgers with blue dashes, chimney bay in red

Deck area 3 - large concrete pad extends about 10' from what is shown in image. Concrete is presumably 4" thick.

Framing plan - joist angle is actual 51°, but that's probably doable with a 45° hanger. I just don't know if I'd need a post by the rim joist. This is using 2x8 joists on a 16" spacing.

